# html - div position, z-index and draggable image

Tags: html, z-index, draggable

Trying for hours various option and readin many post but don't find the solution :D
I'm trying to create an HTML page where there is a background and draggable element on top of this background.
I'm able to make the draggable "box" but it seems my div doesn't care of the position and z-index...
[image: results]

Here my code :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="background" style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;z-index:0;">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NrqfRMG/stack-background.png" width="1260" height="720">
</div>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="width:270px;height:36px;border:1px solid black;position:relative;top:-20;left:300;z-index:2;">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/cJcF1PC/stack-box-1.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="270" height="36">
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="width:270px;height:36px;border:1px solid black;position:relative;top:-20;left:600z-index:2;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you have any idea how to make it work, would be so helpful.
thanks
Pierre :)

Comment: STOP using inline `on*` JS handlers and inline `style` attributes.

Comment: Could you explain: what's the point of that orange DIV element? Does it have anything to do in particular with the dragging DIV? Is it a drop area or just some sample DIV element that uses some vertical space for demo?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="background" style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;z-index:0;">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NrqfRMG/stack-background.png" width="1260" height="720">
</div>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
</div>

<script>
//Make the DIV element draggagle:
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

From [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp).

Edit:

```
<div id="background" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:0;">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NrqfRMG/stack-background.png" width="1260" height="720">
</div>
```

Change the background div to this if you want the box to overlap.

Comment: thanks for try, not this as the box is not overlaying the background at start

Comment: If you want it to overlay the background in the background div, put this "position:absolute;" in style. (see my edit)

Comment: Don't use `on*` handlers if you didn't create the Element as brand new from in-memory. Use addEventListener instead.

Comment: Also, avoid using w3schools as an authoritative learning resource.

Answer (score 0):

With help of @yodamousta, I've been able to make it work :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="background" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:0;">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/NrqfRMG/stack-background.png" width="1260" height="720">
</div>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="width:270px;height:36px;border:1px solid black;position:relative;top:30px;left:300px;z-index:2;">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/cJcF1PC/stack-box-1.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="270" height="36">
</div>

<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" style="width:270px;height:36px;border:1px solid black;position:relative;top:50px;left:600px;z-index:2;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```